# How to shorten loading time with multiple subqueries and joins?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a query to find which v_address belonged to which v_group, and when was the creation date of v_address. However, each v_group was sometimes active and inactive and it has dates. So, I wrote query to find the period of those changes.

My problem is my query took too long time to run because it has multiple subqueries and joins.

Does anyone have a better idea to shorten to load data?
  I attached my query below `identifier = 81` is for smaller testing. For the final result, I will need to retrieve data for more than 100k ids.

I tried to change inner joins to left joins but it loses null values and still took too long time to retrieve data.

```
with v_address as (
    select id, v_group_id, created_at
    from prod.venue_address --different schema and table. v_address.v_group_id can have multiple v_address.id
    group by 1,2,3
    order by 3 asc
    ),
v_group as (
    select identifier, final_status, created_at
    from dwh.venue_address_archive
    where identifier = 81
    group by 1,2,3
    order by 3 asc
    ),
filtering as (
    select identifier, created_at,
    case when sum(case when final_state = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'active' else 'inactive' end as filtered_status --This filters either of active or inactive
    from v_group
    group by 1,2
    order by 2 asc
    ),
prev as (
    select identifier, created_at, filtered_status,
    lag(case when filtered_status = 'active' then 'active' else 'inactive' end) over (partition by identifier order by created_at) = filtered_status as is_prev_status
    from filtering
    group by 1,2,3
    ),
periods as (
    select identifier, filtered_status, created_at, is_prev_status,
    sum(case when is_prev_status = true then 0 else 1 end) over (order by identifier, created_at) as period
    from prev
    group by 1,2,3,4
    ),
islands_gaps_start as (
    select identifier, period, min(created_at) as start_at
    from periods
    group by 2,1
    ),
islands_gaps as (
    select identifier, period, start_at,
    lead(start_at) over (partition by identifier order by period) as end_at
    from islands_gaps_start
    )
select vg.identifier as "vg_id", p.created_at as "vg_created_at", p.filtered_status as "status", p.is_prev_status, p.period, va.id as "va_id", g.start_at, g.end_at
from v_address va
left join v_group vg
on va.venue_id = vg.identifier
inner join filtering f
on vg.identifier = f.identifier
inner join prev pr
on pr.filtered_status = f.filtered_status
inner join periods p
on p.filtered_status = pr.filtered_status
inner join islands_gaps_start gs
on p.period = gs.period
inner join islands_gaps g
on gs.start_at = g.start_at
group by 6,1,2,3,4,5,7,8
order by 2 asc
```

I already have the output with an example `identifier = 81` but I have to run this query for more than 100k identifiers so, I'm looking for any advice that I can shorten my query.

Comment: Does `explain analyze <your_query>` tell you that your problem has to do with the number of subqueries and joins.

Comment: When a query starts looking like this, consider a stored procedure. Stored procedures are pre-optimised by the engine in most cases (where they are not dynamic). They will give you the benefit of loops and structure to potentially build up your filters/etc before you start running them against the actual data set.